# remove field from response output in python

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

Can any suggest how to remove field EventTime from below output in python3 using boto3 .

```
'Events': [{
    'EventId': '4a9f4c8e-3394-41df-xxxx-7e725b7c728e',
    'EventName': 'ConsoleLogin',
    'ReadOnly': 'false',
    'EventTime': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 5, 9, 49, 19, tzinfo = tzlocal()),
    'EventSource': 'signin.amazonaws.com',
    'Username': 'tests.sde',
    'Resources': [],
    'CloudTrailEvent': '{"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? The nice thing about json and/or dictionaries is that you can just ignore the keys/values you don't care about. You rarely need to actively remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response syntax above is just a standard python dictionary.  The one complication with the `boto3` response syntax is the `Events` key is really a dictionary wrapped in a list, but you can still use `pop()` to remove the `EventTime` key from that dictionary.  In the example below I've named the output `response`.

```
response['Events'][0].pop('EventTime', None)
print(response)
```

`pop()` removes keys in-place so after you run the code and look at `response` the `EventTime` key will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple python element deletion from a dictionary. In your case you have a list of dictionaries. If you want to delete `EventTime` in all the dictionaries that are in the `'Events':[{}]`. you can use the below code:

```
for event in response['Events']:
    try:
        del event['EventTime']
    except KeyError:
        print("Key 'EventTime' is not found")
```

The above code will delete the 'EventTime' and throws an error if it doesn't find any element with key `EventTime`. In your case, I guess all the dictionaries will have it.